# How to load dynamic image from assets folder in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I have 2 problems:

1. If I use the variable in src:

I will get this link in the web and not exactly:

```
http://localhost:3000/~/assets/product/image/bg.png
```

2. Similar to the first problem.
   I want to use dynamic css file in head() method:

   export default {
     head () {
       const style = this.$cookie.get('app_style')
       return {
         link: [
           { rel: 'stylesheet', href: `~/assets/${style}.css` }
         ]
       }
     }
   }

Comment: Could you please share a snippet of how you are adding the image?

Comment: Sorry, I have added in the post but it is not displayed.
My example to display image:
<img src="~/assets/${folderType}/bg1.png" />

Comment: I added an answer utilizing the code snippet you gave. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To load dynamic images in the asset folder you can use `require` to tell `webpack` which image to load like so. In your template you can do:

```html
<img :src="require(`../assets/img/${folderType}/bg1.png`)" />
```

Note: assuming `folderType` is defined in your script section

You can extract the require statement into a computed property(would make your template cleaner). So like so:

```js
export default {
  // ...
 data() {
  return {
   folderType: 'folderTypeGoesHere'
}
},
  computed: {
    imagePath () {
      return require(`../assets/img/${this.folderType}/bg1.png`) // the module request
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your template just use:

```html
<img :src="imagePath" />
```

For your second problem, you could resolve to not using the tilde `~` alias and just use a relative path as I did in the image path example above.

Comment: Previously I tried your way, but when looking in the development tool -> network, I saw a request for a path: [object% 20Object]. I don't know if this will affect performance or is it correct?

Comment: This is screenshot:
https://i.ibb.co/F5mh10m/Screen-Shot-2020-06-19-at-09-38-59.png

Comment: hi @AlberZ, did you find any solution about the `[object% 20Object]` issue?